# Python: How to over write output in a label (Tkinter) when using threading.Timer?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, timer

I am writing a program to display the current date, time and weather using the python GUI, Tkinter. The weather details are retrieved using an API from another website. When i run the program, i want the time to be changing (seconds moving etc.) I have looked into threading and timers and i came up with the output below. However, i want the time to over write itself every second, instead of creating a new label every time for each second. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import time 
import threading

url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Athlone,ie&appid=ca8b6f0388c49b7d926706a9c498310d'
data=requests.get(url)
read=data.json()
Cname = ("City Name: {}".format(read['name']))
TempDeg =("Tempterature: {}".format(read['main']['temp'] - 273.15))
WeaDesc =("Description: {}".format(read['weather'][0]['description']))

frame = Tk() #Constructor to make the frame in the background to put widgets on
frame.configure(background='black')
#frame.attributes('-fullscreen', True) #Takes up whole screen, no title bar
frame.state('zoomed') #Takes up whole screen with title bar on top. (Easier to exit when testing)

currentdate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

lbl1 = Label(frame, text=Cname, font=('Times New Roman', 30), fg='white', bg = 'black') 
lbl2 = Label (frame, text=TempDeg + '°C', font=('Times New Roman', 30), fg='white', bg = 'black')
lbl3 = Label (frame, text=WeaDesc, font=('Times New Roman',30), fg='white', bg = 'black')
#lbl4 = Label (frame, text=localtime, font=('Times New Roman',30), fg='white', bg = 'black')
lbl5 = Label (frame, text=currentdate, font=('Times New Roman',30), fg='white', bg = 'black')
lbl6 = Label (frame, text='*Insert complimentary comment here*', font=('Lucida Handwriting', 25), fg = 'white', bg = 'black')

def f():
    localtime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    lbl4 = Label (frame, text=localtime, font=('Times New Roman',30), fg='white', bg = 'black')
    lbl4.pack()
    threading.Timer(1, f).start()

f()
#lbl4.pack()
lbl5.pack()
lbl1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
lbl3.pack()
lbl6.pack()

frame.mainloop() #inifinte loop that allows the window to stay open
```

Ignore the random #Comments, they were inserted by me to help me understand some of the code as i am new to this.

Comment: if all you're doing is updating a clock, you definitely don't need threads. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36280008/7432

Comment: use `root.after(milliseconds, callback)` instead of thread

Comment: @BryanOakley I just used the clock as an example. I would need all the details currently on the GUI updating as i plan to let the program run for hours/days straight.. ?

Comment: You still don't need threads for that, unless the fetching of the data to update the display takes more than a few hundred milliseconds.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay, thanks for the feedback. Just one more question, would i need to use the 'self' argument like the one in the link that you attached in your comment?

Comment: @furas just add that line into my f()?

Comment: @NemanjaBozic: you only use `self` if you are using classes. Here's an example that doesn't use classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17041094/7432

Comment: use `frame.after(1000, f)` instead of  `threading.Timer(1, f).start()`

Comment: @BryanOakley i think i understand. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @furas I did, but the time is still printing itself repeatedly underneath itself every second? I think it could be due to the `lbl4.pack()` ?

Comment: you have to creat Label only once and later in `f()` change text in this label - now you create new label again and agan so you have all this text.

Comment: simple example: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py

Comment: @furas Dziękuję Ci, but i just can't get it to work even after all your help. I'm too much of an amateur..

Comment: BTW: if you speak Polish then on Facabook is [Python Poland](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpl/) and [Python:pierwsze kroki](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpierwszekroki/)

Comment: @furas unfortunately i don't.. i just seen you were from Poland so i thought i would throw in a bit of Polish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
frame.after(1000, f)
```

instead od `threading.Timer(1, f).start()`

You have to create `lbl4` outside function and later in function change text with

```
lbl4['text'] = localtime
#or 
lbl4.config(text=localtime)
```

Working example

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import time 

# --- functions ---

def f():
    localtime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    lbl4['text'] = localtime
    # run again after 1000ms (1s)
    frame.after(1000, f)

# --- main ---

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Athlone,ie&appid=ca8b6f0388c49b7d926706a9c498310d'
data = requests.get(url)
read = data.json()
Cname = "City Name: {}".format(read['name'])
TempDeg = "Tempterature: {}".format(read['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
WeaDesc = "Description: {}".format(read['weather'][0]['description'])

frame = tk.Tk()
frame.configure(background='black')
#frame.attributes('-fullscreen', True) #Takes up whole screen, no title bar
#frame.state('zoomed') #Takes up whole screen with title bar on top. (Easier to exit when testing)

currentdate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

font = ('Times New Roman', 30)

lbl1 = tk.Label(frame, text=Cname, font=font, fg='white', bg='black') 
lbl2 = tk.Label(frame, text=TempDeg+'°C', font=font, fg='white', bg='black')
lbl3 = tk.Label(frame, text=WeaDesc, font=font, fg='white', bg='black')

# empty label
lbl4 = tk.Label(frame, font=font, fg='white', bg='black')

lbl5 = tk.Label(frame, text=currentdate, font=font, fg='white', bg='black')
lbl6 = tk.Label(frame, text='*Insert complimentary comment here*', font=('Lucida Handwriting', 25), fg='white', bg='black')

lbl4.pack()
lbl5.pack()
lbl1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
lbl3.pack()
lbl6.pack()

# run first time
f()

frame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a label text you just have to do:

> lbl4.config(text=localtime)

in your f() function.

You also must define the label *once* by uncommenting the original definition of *lbl4*.  Delete the *pack()* call in f().

Comment: i was a bit confused by your reply.. is this what f() is supposed to look like now?                                                                      def f():                                                                                                                                                                                                      lbl4.config(text=localtime)                                             threading.Timer(1, f).start()